# Initializing jQuery plugin ( $.live() ) - after DOM is loaded

Tags: jquery

I am using this plugin to create charts: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

The code works below if I run it via the console in firebug, but if I have it run in when i reload the page it wont load the chart.

**I am going to guess its that because the parent element is created after the DOM is loaded.**

So I am wondering if I can fire this with jQuery `live()`? Loads like:

- Request user location
- Display single page view (this is where the element is created via JSON data)

Any ideas on how I can get my plugin to fire once the new element is created?

```
$('#snow-line').visualize({type:'bar'});

$('#resort-open').visualize({
    type:'pie',
    colors: ['#658AB6','#FAFAFA']
});
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how I am rendering the data via my JSON object

```
var resortOpenPerc = loadResort.openDownHillPercent;
var ressortOpenDiff = 100-resortOpenPerc;

$("#resort-open tbody tr:eq(0) td:first").html(resortOpenPerc);
$("#resort-open tbody tr:eq(1) td:first").html(ressortOpenDiff);
```

And this error is rendering:

```
Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
domain.com/visualize.js
Line 201
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"So I am wondering if I can fire this with jquery live()?"*

No. The `.live()` method is deprecated presumably in part because it does not convey the fact that it is mere event delegation.

In other words, it works only for handling browser events, not arbitrary code like plugins.

---

You say the elements are created *"with Mustache.js and data is being loaded via JSON"*.

I don't know what that means in your code (because you didn't post it), but if you don't have direct access to the new elements as they're being created, then simply select them *after* they've been added to the DOM, and run the plugin at that time.

```
// code to create new elements...

$('#snow-line').visualize({type:'bar'});

$('#resort-open').visualize({
    type:'pie',
    colors: ['#658AB6','#FAFAFA']
});
```

---

If this doesn't work, then there's some other issue, and you'll need to post your code so that we can see the issue.

Comment: Ah, i will keep that in mind for live(). Check out the code here: http://pastie.org/3185844 - this code is is loaded via a function called: loadSingleResort()

Comment: I added comments on a few lines to give you an idea on what is going on. I am using this for loading the data via JSON. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ - similar to jQuery Template

Comment: And as you said in your example. I was trying to complete that in that order. 

Load data
Create new elements with data
Initialize the charts and render on the screen

Comment: @Coughlin: First, don't use `livequery`. There's almost always a better solution. Second, in your code, you're setting up the `livequery` *after* the elements are added. Not sure what effect that has, but probably doesn't help. *But that doesn't matter since you're not going to use `livequery`, right? ;)* So when you get rid of `livequery`, if it still does't work, then you should inspect the elements using the developer tools to make sure they are showing up with the proper ID attributes. Also, check your console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Sounds good, livequery is gone then! I have it out of the livequery function and is being called right after the elements are created. The thing is that it renders part of the graph. I will setup a section for you can test it, if that is easier.

Comment: Check this out: http://clients.catonthecouch.com/ski/pie.html - that works perfectly without the page generating content after DOM.

Comment: I also added an update to my original question. The last lines is how I am dynamically updating my table data. The chart generates from a table.

Comment: @Coughlin: Alright, so we know that the code is running, but it seems that it halts when it hits the error. If you put up a page that demonstrates the actual error, I *may* be able to figure something out. But not knowing anything about that plugin, I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin for that:

```
$('#snow-line').livequery(function() {
    $(this).visualize({type:'bar'});
});

$('#resort-open').livequery(function() {
    $(this).visualize({
        type:'pie',
        colors: ['#658AB6','#FAFAFA']
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didnt work. I also tried taking that code and running it via console in Firebug and that worked. Maybe its the plugin? But shouldnt it work even it function is called after the new elements are created.

Comment: I am creating my elements with Mustache.js and data is being loaded via JSON